# Количество знаков после запятой в результате функции AVG

Tags: sql, sql-server

Можно ли поставить ограничение на вывод количества знаков после запятой в результате функции AVG?

Слишком длинное число получаются.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/functions/round-transact-sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Тип возвращаемого значения определяется типом вычисленного результата
>   выражения expression.

Таким образом вы можете задать любой тип возвращаемого значения из доступных [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/functions/avg-transact-sql), если предварительно измените тип на входе:
 `SELECT AVG(cast(smth as int)) FROM MyTable`

А также можете самостоятельно привести результат к необходимому, приведением типа:
 `SELECT CAST(AVG(smth) as decimal(5,2)) FROM MyTable`

Подробнее о типе decimal можно прочитать [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql).

Comment: Я бы еще добавил, что при усечении к результату неявно применяется функция round

Comment: @Nick Proskuryakov 
А можете подсказать где тогда вводить название столбца с результатами?

Comment: @MrKris вы имеете ввиду алиас? После скобок напишите as [Name], слово as можно опустить

Comment: @Nick Proskuryakov Огромное спасибо!